# No Suitable Driver Found using JDBC

Tags: java, ms-access, urlconnection

So, I'm having the following issue: there is no suitable driver found for `jdbc://C:/Users/Billy Bob Jones/Documents/My20Y1P2023.accdb` . I am using spaces in my name. So, the error I am getting is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc://C:/Users/Billy Bob Jones/Documents/My20Y1P2023.accdb
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at Ex20_1_2023.main(Ex20_1_2023.java:16)
```

Note that Billy Bob Jones is not the real name I am using on my computer. Those are merely placeholder names that I am using in order to post this.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am thinking the issue stems from me having spaces in my name.

Thank You!

I already tried using a `%20` , a backslash followed by a space, and two backslashes followed by a space, but nothing really worked alongside that.

Comment: Use the [UCanAccess JDBC Driver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/).

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the URL you give to the JDBC driver is incorrect.  I don't know where you got that URL you're supplying.

Your more serious problem might be the driver itself.

Older JDKs used to have a built-in [JDBC-ODBC bridge driver](https://support.migration-center.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012716534-How-to-enable-JDBC-ODBC-bridge-for-Java-8-) that could connect to MS Access, but it's been removed from the JDK since version 8.

[Here](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/java-jdbc-example-connect-to-microsoft-access-database) is a URL that shows you how to do it with an open source ucanaccess JDBC driver.